# Lotsawater screensaver Mavericks problem

Tags: macos

Prior to updating to Mavericks I used LotsaWater screensaver. It would display my desktop while the screensaver did its thing. Now it shows a blank white screen when it kicks over to the screensaver mode.

Under System Prefs>Desktop & Screen saver, the preview window shows how it's supposed to look and if you tap on preview it works right.

Is it that the maker of this screensaver hasn't made it compatible with Mavericks? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version you got.
v1.7 works like a charm for me under Mavericks.

v1.7 is available here: http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/lotsablankers/lotsawater

**Edit:** sorry, it doesn't work exactly as I said. Actually, the water animation works, but the screenshot Lotsawater is supposed to do is a black screen instead.
I assume the v1.7 is not Mavericks (full) compatible.

**Edit 2:** The developer fixed it!, v1.8 is now available and works like a charm :)

**Edit 3:**  1.8 works as expected on a single monitor, but the second monitor of a dual monitor setup still has a black screen shot. This wasn't the case with version 1.7 on Mountain Lion. I hope the developer has another update in the works.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is [here](https://github.com/CrazyHulk/lotsawater). And [my fork](https://github.com/iwill/LotsaWater) fixed some issues, now it can works fine in macOS Ventura 13.1 with dual monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm french. Sorry for my english

I've got the same problem.. Choose the options... Picture... custom.. and choose a picture in your hard disk

Comment: We'll try hard to help with translations as needed. Are you proposing that by choosing some arbitrary picture on your HD, the screen saver will then resume the expected function?

Answer (score 0):

My copy of 1.7 has a custom image option, but there appears to be no way to select any image while running mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the screensaver being sandboxed for security.

Try without the option that requires the password at screensaver exit.